# What is this dry flower?

Tags: identification

It is hard to identify a dry/died plant.
It looks like from Asteraceae family. But don't let me mislead you.
It should be from North America.

[image]

Comment: You may have to break it up and post phots of the inside.

Answer (score 0):

Hard to say without an idea of size or maybe some leaves to look at, but looks like a Centaurea of some sort to me